# Vertical center alignment of text in cell of table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, brackets

I am trying to create following table

[image]

But the problem is that the big round brackets in third column are sitting on the horizontal lines. Is there some way to center align the brackets vertically in an easy manner?

```
\begin{tabular}{ |c | c | c|}

\hline
\rowcolor{myblue} \textcolor{white}{Parabola} & \textcolor{white}{Equation of Tangent} & \textcolor{white}{Point of Contact} \\ 

 \rule{0pt}{25pt}\bm{$y^2=4ax$} & \bm{$\displaystyle y=mx+\frac{a}{m}$} & \bm{$\displaystyle \bigg(\frac{a}{m^2},\frac{2a}{m}\bigg)$}   \\ \hline  
 
\rule{0pt}{25pt}\bm{$y^2=-4ax$} & \bm{$\displaystyle y=mx-\frac{a}{m}$} & \bm{$\displaystyle  \bigg(-\frac{a}{m^2},\frac{2a}{m}\bigg)$}   \\  \hline
  
\rule{0pt}{20pt}\bm{$x^2=4ay$} & \bm{$\displaystyle y=mx-am^2$} & \bm{$\displaystyle \big(2am,am^2\big)$}   \\ \hline  
 
\rule{0pt}{20pt}\bm{$x^2=-4ay$} & \bm{$\displaystyle y=mx+am^2$} & \bm{$\displaystyle \big(-2am,-am^2\big)$}   \\   \hline 

\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Take a look as the `cellspace` package

Comment: wow I wrote `\bm` and I would never have guessed it worked outside math mode. It would be far more efficient to use `\boldmath $x$` than `\bm{$x$}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Why is that? I am a beginner in latex so can't figure out the reason.

Comment: `\bm` is intended to make individual subterms in a larger expression bold, so it is intended to be used _in_ math not around it.  making the whole expression bold is _much_ easier and has always been supported by core latex with no packages at all with `\boldmath`.  `\boldmath` is just a simple font switch , `\bm` has to deconstruct every symbol and reconstitute an equivalent math expression using the bold version of each symbol.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57775397/how-to-center-my-text-vertically-in-a-table-environment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest to use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` which provides parameters `cell-space-bottom-limit` and `cell-space-top-limit` inspired by the lengths `\cellspacebottomlimit` and `\cellspacetoplimit` of the package `cellspace`.

`{NiceTabular}` is designed to give better results than standard `colortbl` in the PDF viewers when rules are used in conjonction with colored panels. However, you need several compilations.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-top-limit=2pt,cell-space-bottom-limit=2pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[hvlines,colortbl-like]
\rowcolor{blue!50} \textcolor{white}{Parabola} & \textcolor{white}{Equation of Tangent} & \textcolor{white}{Point of Contact} \\ 
$y^2=4ax$& $y=mx+\frac{a}{m}$& $\biggl(\frac{a}{m^2},\frac{2a}{m}\biggr)$  \\ 
$y^2=-4ax$ & $y=mx-\frac{a}{m}$ & $ \biggl(-\frac{a}{m^2},\frac{2a}{m}\biggr)$  \\  
$x^2=4ay$ & $y=mx-am^2$& $\bigl(2am,am^2\bigr)$  \\ 
$x^2=-4ay$ & $y=mx+am^2$& $\bigl(-2am,-am^2\bigr)$  \\   
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: Ouput of the above code]

Comment: It is saying "cell-space-top-limit " is unknown for the package nicematrix and few more errors when I build and run.

Comment: I think you have not the latest version of `nicematrix`. You should update your TeX installation (MiKTeX, TeXLive or MacTeX).

Comment: I am new to latex and using overleaf.

Comment: Send me a mail (fpantigny@wanadoo.fr) and I will send you the latest version of  `nicematrix.sty` to upload in Overleaf in the directory of your Overleaf project.

Comment: @Davide Carlisle: Right. I have modified (I had copied the code of the OP without modifying that point).

Answer (score 7):

With use of the `nccmath`, `cellspace`, and `hhline` packages and `array` for table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{cellspace, hhline}
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{array}{ |c | c | >{$}Sc<{$}|}
    \hhline{---}
\rowcolor{blue!50} 
\text{\textcolor{white}{Parabola}} 
        & \text{\textcolor{white}{Equation of Tangent}} 
                & \text{\textcolor{white}{Point of Contact}}   \\
    \hhline{---}
y^2=4ax
    & y=mx+\frac{a}{m}
        & \Bigl(\mfrac{a}{m^2},\mfrac{2a}{m}\Bigr)      \\  \hhline{---}
y^2=-4ax
    & y=mx-\dfrac{a}{m}
        & \Bigl(-\mfrac{a}{m^2},\mfrac{2a}{m}\Bigr)     \\  \hhline{---}
x^2=4ay
    & y=mx-am^2
        & \bigl(2am,am^2\bigr)                          \\ \hhline{---}
{x^2=-4ay}
    & y=mx+am^2
        & \bigl(-2am,-am^2\bigr)                        \\ \hhline{---}
    \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
Version where equation in cells are aligned at equal sign and points at commas:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{cellspace, hhline}
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcw{O{>{\color{white}}Sc|}m}
    {\multicolumn{2}{#1}{#2}}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.5pt}
\setlength\arraycolsep{12pt}
    \begin{array}{ |r@{\,}l | >{\qquad}r@{\,}l | r@{,\,}>{$}Sl<{$}|}
    \hhline{*{6}{-}}
\rowcolor{blue!50}
\mcw[|>{\color{white}}Sc|]{Parabola}
        & \mcw{Equation of Tangent}
                & \mcw{Point of Contact}             \\
    \hhline{*{6}{-}}
y^2 & = 4ax
    & y & =mx+\frac{a}{m}
        & \Bigl(\mfrac{a}{m^2} & \mfrac{2a}{m}\Bigr)    \\  
    \hhline{*{6}{-}}
y^2 & = -4ax
    & y & = mx-\dfrac{a}{m}
        & \Bigl(-\mfrac{a}{m^2} & \mfrac{2a}{m}\Bigr)   \\  
    \hhline{*{6}{-}}
x^2 & = 4ay
    & y & = mx-am^2
        & \bigl(2am & am^2\bigr)                        \\ 
    \hhline{*{6}{-}}
x^2 & = -4ay
    & y & = mx+am^2
        & \bigl(-2am & -am^2\bigr)                      \\ 
    \hhline{*{6}{-}}
    \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any easy way to remove second and third vertical line in first row only?

Comment: @Mathematics, it is possible, but not very easy (you need to use for each cell  `multicolumn` with the same cell align as has column and with content in math mode). BTW, to my taste, this nod lead to nice table. I would rather remove all vertical lines and employ rules from `booktabs` package. However, you accept other answer, which has own specific to  draw vertical lines ... you should ask @F. Pantigny.