# Best way to put aligned equations in a tabular in latex

Tags: tables, align

I want to implement something like this. But I found it's hard to put multiple lines of aligned equations in a cell. I searched a lot, even if I use `\parbox` to make the aligned equations into a cell, I still can't align this cell to the left or top-align the contents in the cells next to it. Below is what I want to have, which is done in MicroSoft Word. Note that the dotted grid lines won't be printed to pdf and are only displayed to show the alignment.
[image]

Here is some imperfect code I've tried. My goals include:

1. A table is prefered over other implementations such as `align`, `framed`. Because I have a very long table about trigonometic functions which must be aligned gracefully.
2. Insert multiple lines of equations in a cell and hopefully (not necessarily) align equations within the same cell at the `=` sign.
3. All cells aligned to top-left without any left margin.
4. Some top and bottom padding is preferred. (I can do it with `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}` now, but I wonder if there's a better way.)

The compiled pdf is pasted below. My current solution somehow causes the weird right shift at the second row. I have no idea what went wrong. Besides, I do not think my solution is the right way anyways.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabular}[t]{|lll|}
  \hline
  \(\sin (x + \pi) = -\sin x\)                        &
  \(\sin (x + \pi) = -\sin x\)                        &
  \(\tan (x + \pi) = \tan x\)                         \\ \hline
  \parbox{100pt}{
    \begin{align*}
       & \sin (\alpha+\beta)   \\
       & = \sin\alpha\cos\beta + \cos\alpha\sin\beta
    \end{align*}
  }                                                  &
  \parbox{100pt}{
    \begin{flalign*}
      & \cos (\alpha+\beta) \\
      & = \sin\alpha\cos\beta + \cos\alpha\sin\beta
    \end{flalign*}
  }                                                  &
  \parbox{100pt}{
    \begin{flalign*}
      & \tan (\alpha+\beta) \\
      & = \frac{\tan\alpha + \tan\beta}{1 - \tan\alpha\tan\beta}
    \end{flalign*}
  }                                                           \\
  \(\sin 2x = 2 \cos x \sin x\)                      &
  \parbox{100pt}{
    \begin{flalign*}
      \cos 2x & = \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x \\
      & = 2\cos^2 x - 1               \\
      & = 1 - 2\sin^2 x
    \end{flalign*}
  }                                                  &
  \(\tan 2x = \frac{2\tan x}{1 - \tan^2 x}\)                  \\
  \(\sin \frac{x}{2} = \sqrt{\frac{1 - \cos x}{2}}\) &
  \(\cos \frac{x}{2} = \sqrt{\frac{1 + \cos x}{2}}\) &
  \(\tan \frac{x}{2} = \sqrt{\frac{1 - \cos x}{1 + \cos x}}\) \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. People are much more likely to help if you supply some compilable code that we can start from.

Comment: Please clarify the degree of necessity of some (so-far implicit) design choices: Must the cell contents be aligned flush-left, or could they be centered within each cell? Shouldn't the `=` symbols in rows 2 and 3 of the formula in the "middle" cell be aligned under the `=` symbol in the first row? Must the three columns be equally wide? Should the *total width* of the table be equal to, say, `\textwidth`, i.e., the width of the text block? Is it essential to use a system of rigid grid lines, or could whitespace be used to provide the required degree of visual separation?

Comment: How should be equation aligned? All in column? See, if apprach in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/559867/vertical-center-alignment-of-text-in-cell-of-table/559885#559885 is what you looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general comment up front: It's not meaningful to claim that some solution is *best* without knowing what the typesetting objectives and constraints may be. Hopefully, the following solution suggestions will be *useful*. For sure, though, I make no claim that they are "best".

The following screenshot and code shows two possible solutions: the first table uses fixed column widths (because that's what's done in the screenshot you posted), whereas the second table uses natural column widths. In my opinion, using natural column widths looks better -- at least for the table at hand.

In both solutions, the cell contents are typeset left-aligned, again because that's what's shown in your screenshot; please advise if you'd prefer some other alignment choice. Do note the use of an `aligned` environment in the "middle" cell to typeset the three-row expression in a way that aligns the three `=` symbols vertically. Finally, in both solutions, I've deliberately omitted all vertical rules and used the macros of the `booktabs` package to create just two visible horizontal rules; this was done in order to give the table a more open and inviting "look".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier} % optional (to match font used in OP's screenshot)
\usepackage{array} % for 'w' col. type and '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{W}[1]{>{$\displaystyle}w{l}{#1}<{$}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\displaystyle}l}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for 'aligned' env.
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{geometry} % (set page parameters suitably)

%% Material that's common to both tables created below:
\newcommand\blurb{% 
  \toprule
  \sin(x+\pi)=-\sin x & \cos(x+\pi)=-\cos x & \tan(x+\pi)=\tan x \\ 
  \addlinespace[2ex]
  \sin2x=2\sin x\cos x & 
  \begin{aligned}[t] % <-- note the 't' ("top") placement specifier
  \cos2x &=\cos^2x-\sin^2x\\
         &=2\cos^2x-1\\
         &=1-2\sin^2x
  \end{aligned} & 
  \tan2x = \frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2x} \\
  \addlinespace[2ex]
  \sin\frac{x}{2}=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos x}{2}} &
  \cos\frac{x}{2}=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos x}{2}} & 
  \tan\frac{x}{2}=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos x}{1+\cos x}} \\
  \addlinespace
  \bottomrule}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{@{} *{3}{W{4cm}} @{}}
\blurb
\end{array}
\]

\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{15pt} % default is '5pt'
\begin{array}{@{} *{3}{L} @{}}
\blurb
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. In the second solution `\begin{array}{@{} *{3}{L} @{}}`, what are `@{}` `*{3}{L}` used for?

Comment: @Neo - The `@{}` particles instruct LaTeX not to insert whitespace padding at the right-hand and left-hand edges of the `array` environment. `*{3}{L}` is shorthand for `LLL` or, in words, "3 columns of type `L`". Similarly, the earlier `*{3}{W{4cm}}` means "3 columns of type `W{4cm}`".

Comment: Two questions about `\newcolumntype{L}{>{\displaystyle}l}`:           1. What is `>` for?
                     2. Unlike `\newcolumntype{W}`, here you don't use `$ $` to enable math mode. How does the second solution magically enter math mode?

Comment: @Neo - The [user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/array.pdf) of the [array package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/array), entitled "A new implementation of LATEX's `tabular` and `array`
environments", provides a lot of useful information. E.g., the `>{...}` and `<{...}` directives "sandwich" a basic column type (here: `l`) between opening and closing directives. In an `array` environment, the `l`, `c`, and `r` column types are *automatically* in math mode -- no "magic" required!. This is *not* the case for the `w` column type; hence the need for `>{$}` and `<{$}`.